# how to send data from frontend to backend with node js

Tags: node.js, frontend, backend

#### Frontend

- I use `ejs` to create forms

```html
<form action="/users/create" method="POST">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
        Id Advance Requisition
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="IdAdvanceRequisition" name="IdAdvanceRequisition" required/>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
        NoRef
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="NoRef" name="NoRef" required/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
        NIK
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nik" name="Nik" required/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" />
    <a href="/users/index" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Back</a>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Save</button>
</form>
```

- `router` for the router on the frontend, why can I only use post and get? whereas to delete and update you have to use DELETE and PUT

```js
const express = require('express');
const user = require('../controllers/user')
var cors = require('cors')

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/index', user.getUsers);

router.get('/add', user.getAdd);

router.post('/create',cors (), user.createUsers);

router.get('/detail/:id', user.readUsers);

router.post('/delete/:id', cors (), user.deleteUsers);

router.get('/edit/:id', user.detailUpdate);

router.post('/update/:id',cors (), user.updateUsers);

module.exports = router;
```

- `controllers` for add

```js
createUsers : async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const Backend = await getBackend();
        const dataBackend = await Backend.json();

        const user = {id: uuidv4(), IdAdvanceRequisition: req.body.IdAdvanceRequisition, NoRef: req.body.NoRef, Nik: req.body.Nik};
        dataBackend.push({...user, id: uuidv4()});

        fetch('http://localhost:8000/users', {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify(user)
        })
        console.log(`Data with the id: ${user.id} added to the database!`);
        res.redirect('/users/index');
    } catch (error) {
        res.send(`data error`);
    }
}
```

---

#### Results

```
[{"id":"3cc4ed6e-5974-4661-ade7-ec448ac0e7e3"}]
```

**Problem:** I tried to send all data to the backend, but only the UUID was sent. How can I solve this problem

Comment: Paste Code, not Screenshots

Comment: OK, this is my first question on https://stackoverflow.com/, I'm sorry for that

Comment: what does you form have, what do are other data that you are posting. console.log(user) before dataBackend.push. show html form for adding user